# Once bind with live func

Tags: jquery, live, die

How can I once bind click with live function?

I tried:

```
$('.expansion_button').die('click', function(){
   $('.expansion_button').live('click', expansion);
});
```

But this, twice bind click after ajax query;

How can i fixed?

(my english is poor)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly try this

```
$('.expansion_button').one('click', function(){
   alert('Next click will not alert!');
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SUzuD/) is the working demo of above code

Answer (score 1):

If you want the live handler to execute only once per matched element, do something like this:

```
$('.expansion_button').live('click', function(e){

    if( $.data( this, "liveclicked" ) ) {
    return true;
    }

$.data( this, "liveclicked", true );
return expansion.apply( this, arguments );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery .die() kills the handler that you had attached to that element.  In order to bind it you just use live as you did:

```
 $('.expansion_button').live('click', expansion);
```

Then somewhere in that function if you want to remove the bound event you then call .die(), so something like:

```
$("unbind-element").click(function () { 
  $(expansion_button).die(); 
});
```